# Induced Isomorphism between Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain, N,M and P finite generated $R-$modules.
If we have $N \oplus P \cong M \oplus P$ how can be proved that $N \cong M$?

My first atempt was to factorise $ 0 \oplus P$ at both sides but if we have
a not canonical isomorphism, for example $\phi: N \oplus N \to N \oplus N, 
(n_1, n_2) \to (n_2, n_1)$ the sugested induced morphism $\bar{\phi}: 
N \oplus N / 0 \oplus P \to N \oplus N 0 \oplus P$ become a zero morphism.
Has anybody an other idea?

Comment: This follows from the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), but perhaps your question is part of the proof.

Comment: So it follows instantly by comparing separately the free and the torsion components of the quotient modules $N \oplus N / 0 \oplus P$ and $M \oplus N / 0 \oplus P$ using the uniqueness of the classified representations?